# jQuery: Selecting td without a specific element

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to style some table cells that do **not** have an input tag in them. I have a [jsFiddle set up](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/JsTjK/), so you're welcome to make changes there.

As you can see, the top row has an input that is also being affected by the jquery-enabled css, so my selector isn't quite right.

Elsewhere in my site I'm using this:

`$('#content p a:not([href^="http"])').addClass("internalLink");`

to (successfully) find internal links in my text, so I was basing the table cells selector on that, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong...

Thanks for anyone's help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JsTjK/9/

```
$('#hostingInfo td:not(:has(input))').css('text-align', 'right');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JsTjK/5/)**

```
$('#hostingInfo tr').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find("input").length == 0;
}).find("td").css('text-align', 'right');
```

Comment: Thanks, Shankar. That does indeed work. Could you explain what exactly the function is doing? All I'm getting out of that (in my limited experience) is "look in <tr>s and find inputs with length of 0". Which I know isn't quite right. What's the correct way to read that?

Comment: His method is searching the <tr> tags in hostingInfo for the string "input", which returns if it's not found, causing the filter to return true and triggering the .find() call, which will locate <td>'s inside the searched <tr> and set the css style on them. I don't think this is what you want as the labels for the inputs are not going to be right-aligned when that row contains an input (even if it's a different <td>).

Comment: Np, and that should say "which returns 0 length if it's not found".

Comment: @eventide - I was out but you got the explaination thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#hostingInfo td').not(':has(input)').css('text-align', 'right');
```

You can use `not()` method to select everything that does not satisfy a selector in jQuery.

Comment: @Shankar, Artsemis, and ivnatod: All three of those work, and I'm sure there are some other ways to make that happen as well. jQuery is awesome, but, man there's a million ways to do the same thing! I could only select one for the answer, unfortunately, so I selected the first one that was the shortest solution (sorry Shankar!) :)